# A problem about the sign of pitch angle in rotation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The sign of pitch angle in rotation.

In the Yaw-Pitch-Roll convention, for example, XYZ-Zup coordinates system.

When I'm reading page 194-195 of 《Linear Algebra with Applications》 7ED, of STEVEN J.LEON

I have this question, In the example of concrete value 45, -30, 45, I've understood.

My question is why in the general version of rotation matrix of Pitch, the matrix is

\begin{align}\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos  v & 0 & -\sin  v \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \sin  v & 0 & \cos  v \\
\end{array}\end{align}

Is there a sign limit of the Pitch angle, how to decide the direction of the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are doing.  If you have only one observation of a vehicle, the observation will be the same if pitch is increased by $360^\circ$ or any integer multiple.  If you have only one observation, it makes sense to restrict pitch to an interval of $360^\circ$, usually $0-360$ or $-180 \text{ to } 180$ with one end open and one closed (take your pick).  If you are following a vehicle, it makes sense to assume pitch is continuous, so you resolve the $360^\circ$ ambiguity by taking the closest value to the last observation.  The trig functions won't care, which is why you can do either.  If you want to use successive observations to define a pitch rate, I recommend the second.

Comment: Hi, I want to know the rotation's direction, how to define the direction.

Comment: Generally you pick a set of body axes, $x,y,z$ that are in a right hand configuration.  For an airplane, $+x$ is forward, $+z$ is down, and $+y$ is to the right.  A figure is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics).  Then +roll is a positive rotation around $x$, a bank to the right, +pitch is positive around $y$, nose up, and +yaw is positive around $z$, a turn to the right.  You can choose your axes however you want, but it is good to follow the right hand rule when linking axes to rotation.